# How to use function types in interfaces in Go

Tags: go, syntax

I have the following code

```
type SomeInterface interface {
    SomeFunc(int, string)
}

type IntStringFunc func(int, string)

func (f IntStringFunc) SomeFunc(i int, s string) {
    f(i, s)
}
```

What is the syntax for invoking the method SomeFunc on the function type IntStringFunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [calling](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls) syntax does not depend on the receiver type, it's always the same: `value.methodName(params)`.

For example:

```
var f IntStringFunc = func(i int, s string) {
    fmt.Printf("f(%d, %s)\n", i, s)
}

f.SomeFunc(1, "one")
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iq6NyoTu4iK)):

```
f(1, one)
```

Since type of `f` is a function type, you can of course call it too like this:

```
f(1, "one")
```

Which of course will print the same.